# Javascript/React: how to create dynamic variable names for a hook in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use useAnimation() hook to animate a bunch of divs, like

```
const anim0 = useAnimation()
const anim1 = useAnimation()
const anim2 = useAnimation()
const anim3 = useAnimation()
...
```

Is there an easier way creating this in a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array instead:

```
const animations = Array.from(
  { length: 4 },
  useAnimation
);
```

and then reference, eg, `animations[0]` instead of `anim0`.